# Rails Common Assets Except for one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've not been able to find the answer to this. I can load controller specific assets but that would be cumbersome as I add new controllers to my app (been there).

Is there a way to have common assets ie:

```
require tree .
```

But then have one controller which ignores those assets and loads only its own?

I want a home page that has unique css and js. Then once logged in (devise) the other assets are used because it would be a dashboard once logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `//= stub controller_name` in application.js and `*= stub controller_name` in application.css

Comment: Do you mean *= stub controller_name in application.css? Then load the custom assets in the controller_name.scss and contorller_name.js?

Comment: When attempting this method, I have the scss importing the relevant file for the controller_name.scss. Which works, until I *= stub controller_name. If I put it before or after *= require_tree it still stubs out the imported css files so there is no styling on that controller at all.

Comment: You should put it after the require_tree.. You can refer to this blog post http://atlwendy.ghost.io/exclude-some-stylesheets-in-rails-4/

Comment: Worked once I added '<%= stylesheet_link_tag  'controller_name' %> ' to t he markup, 'Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( controller_name.scss )' to the assets file and put ' around controller_name in the application.css Thanks!